# Why do some misbehaving processes use 100% CPU and some 50% CPU?

Tags: windows, multi-processor

When programs on my laptop crash, they sometimes start hogging CPU. I have noticed that some processes use 50% (like firefox, various games) but a few use 100% like (VLC, GOM) etc.

Does this have do with Core2Duo processor on my laptop? Also what determines whether they will use 50% or 100%?

Answer (score 5):

Single-threaded applications will use 50%, or one of the cores on the system fully. Multi-threaded apps will use 100%, or both cores.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that firefox would be running on a single thread.

Comment: You're welcome to pick through the source code.

Comment: @apoorv020 It may only take a single thread/process to hog a CPU core for the entire application to hang.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that if the **portion** of the program that was using the processing power is single-threaded, it will not use more than 50% CPU on a Dual Core (or 25% on a Quad Core).